# YouTube Playlist "Not Found"

Tags: youtube-api, gdata-api

Link to playlist: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL89275CCCD333C8EE

Should be RSS from playlist: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL89275CCCD333C8EE

Says: "Playlist Not Found"

I have found no references to privacy settings of any sorts that may not be set.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two items changed and i can not comfirm whether just one or both comprise the full solution.

First...
Custom channel URL was created

Second...
In the URL above, remove the 'PL' from the list URL argument.  None of the examples I had seen online made any mention of this, but once you remove the 'PL' (playlist?) and only use the id: 89275CCCD333C8EE it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL89275CCCD333C8EE?v=2&alt=jsonc

but you require an authentication also to work the above if the playlist is private.

As it works fine in my case:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL0F32F77A67A612A3?v=2&alt=jsonc

Answer (score 0):

Okay here it is...

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/IDCsync/playlists/89275CCCD333C8EE

Its working

[image: Playlist]

[image: xml]

Comment: You can add **?v=2** at the end of the URL and you get a slighly different version of playlist